# jquery setInterval with fadeOut/In

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little question, about jQuery

when I wrote code like this:

```
<div id="backgroundfade"></div>
$(document).ready(function()  {
   $("#backgroundfade").fadeOut(1000 );
   $("#backgroundfade").fadeIn(1000 );
};
```

but when I want to use setInterval:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
   setInterval(function(){
      $("#backgroundfade").fadeOut(1000 );
      $("#backgroundfade").fadeIn(1000 );
   }, 3000);
};


$("#backgroundfade")
```

this return null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `$("#backgroundfade")` returning `null`? For jQuery, $() is never returning `null` ...

Comment: If you mean $('#backgroundfade') is an empty jQuery object, then that means an element with that ID isn't in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Both your code blocks are missing a closing `)` which will cause an error and cause them not to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#backgroundfade").fadeOut(1000 );
    $("#backgroundfade").fadeIn(1000 );
});

$(document).ready(function()  {
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#backgroundfade").fadeOut(1000 );
        $("#backgroundfade").fadeIn(1000 );
    }, 3000);
});
```

---

FYI, you can simplify the last one a bit to this:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#backgroundfade").fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cUJcA/

---

It isn't clear what you mean when you say "this return null".  `$("#backgroundfade")` creates a jQuery object which is never `null`.